# pandas pivot_table to get the avg value in columns and rows

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, pivot-table

I have the following `df`

```
code    y_m        date_1        date_2
10     201710      2017-10-01    2017-10-06
10     201710      2017-10-07    2017-10-09
10     201711      2017-11-06    2017-11-08
10     201711      2017-11-02    2017-11-06
20     201710      2017-10-03    2017-10-04
20     201710      2017-10-07    2017-10-08
20     201711      2017-11-06    2017-11-09
20     201711      2017-11-02    2017-11-03
```

`code` and `y_m` are `str`, `date_1/2` are `ISODate`.

I want to first groupby `code` and `y_m`, and calculate `date_2-date_1` to create a new column `avg_days` for `Timedelta` values in each group,

```
code_yr_mon_grp_by = df.groupby(['code', 'y_m'])

code_yr_mon_gr_avg_days = code_yr_mon_grp_by.apply(lambda row: (row['date_2'] - row['date_1']) / np.timedelta64(1, 'D')).mean(level=[0, 1]).reset_index(name='avg_days')
```

which will generate

```
code   y_m      avg_days
10    201710     3.5
10    201711     3
20    201710     1
20    201711     2
```

and then I want to convert this df into a matrix that transposes column `y_m` to row, make the `avg_days` as matrix cell values like,

```
     0     1        2            3             
0   -1     0     201710       201711       
1   0     2.375     2.25         2.5           
2   10    3.25      3.5          3                      
3   20    1.5       1            2
```

in specific, `-1` represents a dummy value that indicates either a value doesn't exist for a y_m for a specific `code` or to maintain the matrix shape; `0` represents 'all' values, that averages the `code` or `y_m` or `code` and `y_m`, e.g. cell (1, 1) averages the `avg_days` values for all `y_m` and `code`; `(1,2)` averages the `avg_days` for `201710` across `code` `10` and `20`.

But when I tried

```
def convert_to_matrix(df, p_tab_idx, p_tab_cols, p_tab_vals, p_tab_agg_func):
    df_tab = (df.pivot_table(index=p_tab_idx,
                         columns=p_tab_cols,
                         values=p_tab_vals,
                         margins=True,
                         aggfunc=p_tab_agg_func,
                         fill_value=-1,
                         margins_name='0'))

    # change order of index and columns values for reindex
    idx = df_tab.index[-1:].tolist() + df_tab.index[:-1].tolist()
    cols = df_tab.columns[-1:].tolist() + df_tab.columns[:-1].tolist()

    df_tab = (df_tab.reindex(index=idx, columns=cols)
          .reset_index()
          .rename(columns={p_tab_idx: -1})
          .rename_axis(None, 1))

    # add columns to first row
    df_tab = df_tab.columns.to_frame().T.append(df_tab).reset_index(drop=True)
    # reset columns names to range
    df_tab.columns = range(len(df_tab.columns))
    # converts column labels from int to str
    df_tab.columns = df_tab.columns.astype(str)

    return df_tab

code_yr_mon_gr_proc_days_p_tab = convert_to_matrix(code_yr_mon_gr_avg_days,
                                                    p_tab_idx='code',
                                                    p_tab_cols='y_m',
                                                    p_tab_vals='avg_days',
                                                    p_tab_agg_func='mean')
```

I got error

```
builtins.AttributeError: 'Index' object has no attribute 'to_frame'
```

I am wondering how to fix the issue and achieve the desired result.

Comment: What is your pandas version? I test it in `pandas 0.22.0` and working nice. Maybe version bellow `0.21.0` ? [`to_frame`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Index.to_frame.html) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If pandas version is bellow `0.21.0` where [`Index.to_frame`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Index.to_frame.html) is not implemented use:

```
df_tab = (pd.DataFrame(df_tab.columns, index=df_tab.columns)
            .T
            .append(df_tab)
            .reset_index(drop=True))
```

instead:

```
df_tab = df_tab.columns.to_frame().T.append(df_tab).reset_index(drop=True)
```